# Why does it require four vectors to calculate a torsion angle?

Tags: python

The BioPython documentation shows the following:

> 11.6.3 Measuring torsion angles Use the vector representation of the atomic coordinates and the calc dihedral function from the Vector module:
>
> ```
> >>> vector1 = atom1.get_vector()
> >>> vector2 = atom2.get_vector()
> >>> vector3 = atom3.get_vector()
> >>> vector4 = atom4.get_vector()
> >>> angle = calc_dihedral(vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4)
> ```

We know that a torsion angle between N-Cα and Cα-C planes.

So, the minimum number of points required to form a plane is 3.

Then, Why does BioPython require 4 vectors?